# Getting context in non-activity class comparator

Tags: java, android, comparator, android-context

I have to access my database from the comparator class from one of my entity-classes. 
For instancing the database connection I need an application context.

How do I get the application context in this case:

Entity - class with comparator

```
static public class CowLastInspectionComparator implements Comparator<Cow> {
    public int compare(Cow cow1, Cow cow2) {
        DbAdapter adapter = DbAdapter.getInstance(new MainView().getApplicationContext()); //this doesn't work
        List<Inspection> inspectionsCow1 = adapter.getInspectionByCow(cow1);
        List<Inspection> inspectionsCow2 = adapter.getInspectionByCow(cow2);

        return inspectionsCow1.get(0).getJob().getJobDate().compareTo(inspectionsCow2.get(0).getJob().getJobDate());
    }
}
```

Sorting in Activity:

```
 if (sortOption == "Name") Collections.sort(cows, new Cow.CowLastInspectionComparator());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static public class CowLastInspectionComparator implements Comparator<Cow> {
  private Context context;
  CowLastInspectionComparator(Context context){
    this.context=context;
  }
  public int compare(Cow cow1, Cow cow2) {
    DbAdapter adapter = DbAdapter.getInstance(context); //this doesn't work
    List<Inspection> inspectionsCow1 = adapter.getInspectionByCow(cow1);
    List<Inspection> inspectionsCow2 = adapter.getInspectionByCow(cow2);

    return inspectionsCow1.get(0).getJob().getJobDate().compareTo(inspectionsCow2.get(0).getJob().getJobDate());
  }
}
```

in Activity:

```
 if (sortOption == "Name"){
    Cow.CowLastInspectionComparator comparator=new Cow.CowLastInspectionComparator(this);
    Collections.sort(cows,comparator);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to access my database from the comparator class from one of my entity-classes

If by this you mean that you want to do database I/O in `compare()`, that is going to make your `compare()` calls slow and your `sort()` calls **very** slow. If you want to sort your, um, cows, and they are not all in memory, do a *single* database query with an `ORDER BY` clause to get them properly sorted.

> For instancing the database connection I need an application context.

You need a `Context`. It would not necessarily have to be an `Application`.

> How do I get the application context in this case

Supply one to the `CowLastInspectionComparator`, such as via a constructor parameter.